# Duplicates returned in query on child object

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a data structure in my document like this (note this is simplified for brevity):

```js
{
    "id": "c1c1c1c1-c1c1-c1c1-c1c1-c1c1c1c1c1c1",
    "name": "Bruce Banner",
    "accountId": "a1a1a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1a1a1a1a1",
    "contributors": [{
        "accountId": "a2a2a2a2-a2a2-a2a2-a2a2-a2a2a2a2a2a2",
        "type": "Foo"
    },{
        "accountId": "a3a3a3a3-a3a3-a3a3-a3a3-a3a3a3a3a3a3",
        "type": "Bar"
    }]
},
{
    "id": "c2c2c2c2-c2c2-c2c2-c2c2-c2c2c2c2c2c2",
    "name": "Tony Stark",
    "accountId": "a2a2a2a2-a2a2-a2a2-a2a2-a2a2a2a2a2a2",
    "contributors": [{
        "accountId": "a1a1a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1a1a1a1a1",
        "type": "Fizz"
    }]
},
```

I am attempting to write a query which retrieves documents where the provided `accountId` is either on the parent record or within the `contributors` array:

```sql
SELECT e.id, e.accountId, e.name
FROM Entitity e
JOIN co IN e.contributors
WHERE e.accountId = 'a1a1a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1a1a1a1a1'
OR co.accountId = 'a1a1a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1a1a1a1a1'
```

Result:

```js
[{
    "id": "c1c1c1c1-c1c1-c1c1-c1c1-c1c1c1c1c1c1",
    "accountId": "a1a1a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1a1a1a1a1",
    "name": "Bruce Banner"
},{
    "id": "c1c1c1c1-c1c1-c1c1-c1c1-c1c1c1c1c1c1",
    "accountId": "a1a1a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1a1a1a1a1",
    "name": "Bruce Banner"
},{
    "id": "c2c2c2c2-c2c2-c2c2-c2c2-c2c2c2c2c2c2",
    "accountId": "a2a2a2a2-a2a2-a2a2-a2a2-a2a2a2a2a2a2",
    "name": "Tony Stark"
}]
```

As you can see, the first entity (`Bruce Banner`) is duplicated. If I remove the `JOIN` clause it works correctly. Can anyone tell me why this is, and how I can avoid the duplication?

*Edit* - For clarity, this is my expected response:

```js
[{
    "id": "c1c1c1c1-c1c1-c1c1-c1c1-c1c1c1c1c1c1",
    "accountId": "a1a1a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1a1a1a1a1",
    "name": "Bruce Banner"
},{
    "id": "c2c2c2c2-c2c2-c2c2-c2c2-c2c2c2c2c2c2",
    "accountId": "a2a2a2a2-a2a2-a2a2-a2a2-a2a2a2a2a2a2",
    "name": "Tony Stark"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are trying to query on whether the `accountId` or the `contributors`'s `accountId` is equal to some value.

Today - you need to use the `JOIN` operator to perform a cross-product in order to query across all elements within a JSON array (note: you do not need a `JOIN` to query on a specific array index, e.g. `WHERE e.contributors[0].accountId  = 'a1a1a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1a1a1a1a1'`).

In your example abpve, you will get duplicates from the query which is unavoidable. You will want to implement some application logic to filter duplicates out of the query result.

To get a better picture in to the behavior of `JOIN` (think simple cross product), try adding a field from the array you are producing a cross product with (e.g. `co.type`):

```
SELECT e.id, e.accountId, e.name, co.type
FROM Entitity e
JOIN co IN e.contributors
WHERE e.accountId = 'a1a1a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1a1a1a1a1'
OR co.accountId = 'a1a1a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1a1a1a1a1'
```

which results in:

```
[{
    id: c1c1c1c1 - c1c1 - c1c1 - c1c1 - c1c1c1c1c1c1,
    accountId: a1a1a1a1 - a1a1 - a1a1 - a1a1 - a1a1a1a1a1a1,
    name: Bruce Banner,
    type: Foo
}, {
    id: c1c1c1c1 - c1c1 - c1c1 - c1c1 - c1c1c1c1c1c1,
    accountId: a1a1a1a1 - a1a1 - a1a1 - a1a1 - a1a1a1a1a1a1,
    name: Bruce Banner,
    type: Bar
}, {
    id: c2c2c2c2 - c2c2 - c2c2 - c2c2 - c2c2c2c2c2c2,
    accountId: a2a2a2a2 - a2a2 - a2a2 - a2a2 - a2a2a2a2a2a2,
    name: Tony Stark,
    type: Fizz
}]
```

As you can see from the results - a record is being returned for each of the children: `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Fizz`. That is because each of those array elements match the specified query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this still results in the duplicate entity in the response - there should be only 2 items returned, one for `Bruce Banner` and one for `Tony Stark`. The `type` in this case is irrelevant, I only wish to retrieve distinct records where the supplied account id is either the owner or contributor. I'll update my question to include the desired response.

Comment: Ah gotcha... Unfortunately for this example - duplicates from the query are unavoidable (for the reasons explained in my answer above). You will need to write some application logic to filter the results :(