# CosmosDB + group by

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need to use "**GROUP BY**" clause on **Azure Data Explorer** but I think it is **unsupported**.

Someone have any idea to solve or avoid group by?

Best regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, Azure Cosmos DB currently supports [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-group-by) in .NET SDK 3.3 or later. Support for other language SDK's and the Azure Portal is not currently available but is planned.

```
<group_by_clause> ::= GROUP BY <scalar_expression_list>

<scalar_expression_list> ::=
          <scalar_expression>
        | <scalar_expression_list>, <scalar_expression>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no group by in Azure Data Explorer as of now. However, there is the summarize operator that can help achieve many of the things that you would use GROUP BY for in SQL.

You can find it at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/summarizeoperator

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos DB doesn't support `group by` feature,you could vote up [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/18561901-add-group-by-support-for-aggregate-functions) if you have urgent need.

Provide a third-party package [documentdb-lumenize](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-lumenize) for your reference here which supports group by feature,it has `.net` example:

```
string configString = @"{
    cubeConfig: {
        groupBy: 'state', 
        field: 'points', 
        f: 'sum'
    }, 
    filterQuery: 'SELECT * FROM c'
}";
Object config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(configString);
dynamic result = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<dynamic>("dbs/db1/colls/coll1/sprocs/cube", config);
Console.WriteLine(result.Response);
```

You could group by `assetId` column and get the max `timestamp`.

Besides,you could refer to my previous case:[how to count distinct value in cosmos DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50637169/how-to-count-distinct-value-in-cosmos-db/50734034#50734034) to use stored procedure to implement some aggregation features.

Comment: Best to just mark this question as a duplicate, since the GROUP BY question has been asked (and answered) *many* times (including https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270125/alternative-to-group-by-for-cosmos-db).