# Cant get identifier and Max Value CosmostDb

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb, nosql-aggregation

I would like to do some reporting on my CosmosDb

my Query is

```
Select Max(c.results.score) from c
```

That works but i want the id of the highest score then i get an exception

```
Select c.id, Max(c.results.score) from c
```

> 'c.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in an
>   aggregate function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find duplicates in a nested array in cosmos db without GROUP BY and COUNT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586721/how-to-find-duplicates-in-a-nested-array-in-cosmos-db-without-group-by-and-count)

Answer (score 3):

you can execute following query to archive what you're asking (thought it can be not very efficient in RU/execution time terms):

```
Select TOP 1 c.id, c.results.score from c ORDER BY c.results.score DESC
```

Comment: it is very efficient if `c.results.score` is indexed by a range index.

Answer (score 0):

Group by isn't supported natively in Cosmos DB so there is no out of the box way to execute this query.

To implement this using the out of the box functionality you would need to create a new document type that contains the output of your aggregation e.g.

{
"id" : 1,
"highestScore" : 1000
}

You'd then need a process within your application to keep this up-to-date.

There is also documentdb-lumenize that would allow you to do this using stored procedures. I haven't used it myself but it may be worth looking into as an alternative to the above solution.

Link is:

https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-lumenize

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY is now supported in Cosmos, so your query would read:

```
Select c.id, Max(c.results.score) from c Group By c.id
```