# CosmosDB count, sum in the same query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Does anyone have an idea how to perform multiple counts in CosmosDB in one select?

We log users visits inside CosmoDB, with a fairly simple structure

```
 Userid,
 Type,
 AccessDate
 TimeSpentOnPage
```

Whey type can have value News, Event or Data depending on the type of the page a user accessed

I want to get for each user an type of the page total number of visits and total time spent.

In sql this would be super easy with group by

`Select UserId, Type, count(type), sum(TimeSpentOnPage)
From AccessRecord
GroupBy UserId, Type`

As far as I’m aware GroupBy doesn’t exist in CosmoDB.

Any idea how to implement this query?

Thanks

Comment: As you already said, cosmosdb doesn't support aggregated queries so you'd probably have to get around it with a UDF or an SP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find duplicates in a nested array in cosmos db without GROUP BY and COUNT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586721/how-to-find-duplicates-in-a-nested-array-in-cosmos-db-without-group-by-and-count)

Comment: @NickChapsas - slight correction: Cosmos DB's SQL API doesn't support `GROUP BY` (which is what the OP asserted). It *does* support aggregated queries (min/max/avg/sum/count).

Comment: @DavidMakogon correct. I assumed he already knew that mix/max etc are supported same way he knew group by isn't. Should be more specific.

Comment: @NickChapsas - it's not necessarily about the OP; it's really about other people reading your comments and misinterpreting. Just look at the link Sajeetharan posted, as a possible duplicate (which really isn't a duplicate, though it also tries to address lack of GROUP BY), in which Sajeetharan makes the same statement, in the posted answer (which I called out there, as well). Posted like this enough, and people start to interpret it as "there are no aggregations."

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm aware of the aggregated functions but they just return a scalar. What I need are count and sum for each instance of `UserId` and `Type`

Comment: @NickChapsas, I think you should write the UDF/SP workaround as answer. The comments section is intended for clarification of Q, not answers. You could also fix the little wording mishap in the process + providing a few links to the acronyms;)